# Getting a black screen with horizontal colored lines while booting the Tails OS

Tags: linux, boot, tails-os

I'm in the process of booting the latest version of Tails (5.18) from my Acer laptop (E1-510-2683). To configure my USB, I followed the official Tails documentation. When I attempt to boot, **Im getting a black screen with horizontal colored lines**. Later, I used the same USB to boot up a different laptop, and that got booted and worked without any problems. so **USB is not a problem**. moreover, I can boot a different OS on my Acer laptop, so the **USB port on the laptop is also functional**. I therefore hope that it will be a graphic card issue.

Note: I can see the Tails boot menu (which includes Boot from External Hard Drive, Debug Mode, and Tails). I receive a black screen with those lines whenever I select any.

by searching on the internet, I tried below commands in the Kernel parameters.. `nomodeset, vga=normal, vga=999, nosplash, deleting (live-media=removable)` etc. but I'm getting the same output.

could u please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Acer laptop E1-510-2683 has one of those infamous "Bay Trail" CPU/GPU, not from one of the most problematic branches but still problematic in Linux. Unfortunately, if `nomodeset` doesn't work, nothing will.